# Change user input for python

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

i want to change user input, for example if a user puts in TT0101 i want my script to change it to TT7101 instead, i'm not able to find how to do this anywhere and am now wondering if it's even possible and if so where can i look into it?

Comment: What is the criteria to change? Is it at a specific index always or does it change based on something else?

Comment: Not clear where you want to change it. Do you want to change it on the screen where the user typed it? Or is it just the value of user's input you need to change? How do you get the user's input in the first place? You may want to update your question to include these details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you want to achive, but I can try to answer your specific example.
Just replace the char you want to change.

```
# user input
user_input = input("enter input:")

# user enters TT0101 so user_input equals "TT0101"

# replace first occurence of 0 with 7 
unser_input_changed = user_input.replace("0", "7", 1)

# prints TT7101
print(user_input_changed)
```

[more info on the replace function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)